# rails 4 - images not showing in Heroku using Paperclip & Dropbox.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Installed Paperclip & dropbox to upload images to my application. It works in localhost but not in Heroku. It does upload an image but not from dropbox. Dropbox has been authorised with the app as well. And i get no error messages.

dropbox.yml

```
app_key: "8rv2dcplixxxxxx"
app_secret: <%= ENV["APP_SECRET"] %>
access_token: "u9g1r2p59xxxxxxx"
access_token_secret: <% ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"] %>
user_id: "397xxxxx"
access_type: "app_folder"
```

application.yml

```
APP_SECRET: "gf5tg903xxxxxxx"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: "gpgc7xxxxxxx"
```

this is confirmed when i run heroku config

listing.rb

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  if Rails.env.development?

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)

  else


    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png), 
    :storage => :dropbox,
    :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
    :path => ":style/:id_:filename"
    end

  validates :name, :description, :price, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
  validates_attachment_presence :image

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :orders
end
```

Comment: Is rails setup to serve your static assets? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#injected-plugins

Comment: yes setup correcty retested but heroku not showing the images

Comment: what do your logs show? They should register requests for the static resources

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed the Figaro gem along with Paperclip and Dropbox gems?

Not sure why their github page isn't showing this command anymore, but this worked for me:
`rake figaro:heroku` prepares your app for Heroku.

[Figaro Gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)